# Flutter broken emojis to random characters only

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app emojis seems to be broken

[image: broken]

only if the navigator route is '/'.

Whereas on all other routes it uses

Default system emojis

[image: Default system emojis]

System default emojis are visible on all other routes.

Same error on debug as well as production release.

Flutter version 3.3.9
Dart version 2.18.5

Expected emojis to be visible on all routes

Comment: Need more info... screenshot, code, etc. What exactly does "broken" mean?

Comment: Screenshot attached

Comment: Ok, I haven't experienced that issue, but I've had different issues with emojis. Just as a test, you could try setting a `TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Apple Color Emoji')` or `fontFamilyFallback` for iOS (or whatever the equivalent font family is on Android) on the text. Perhaps that will lead somewhere, like maybe somewhere a theme is altering the font family or fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing "Content-type: application/json" header from my golang application server for the API route '/'